# Saving PHP Variables To Be Used On Many Pages

Tags: if-statement, parameters, request, session-storage

I'm currently trying to make specific adblocks. My code's below.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$isLayout   =   0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['layout']) && ($_REQUEST['layout'] == 'source1')){
$isLayout = 1;
$_SESSION["isLayout"] = 1;  }
```

So currently, this is reading the URL parameters and if ?layout=source1 is appended to the end of the URL, specific changes will be shown on the website. My code to make that happen is below.

```
        <?php 
        if($isLayout == 0){
            echo 'nothing';
        }else{
            echo 'magic that's only to be seen if users come to website from source 1'
        }
        ?>
```

So currently, I got the code to work on the first page visited by the user. However, when that user visits other pages of the website even if they come from source1, the layout goes back to the default. I want to make sure that they site's changes are consistent through the users entire session on the website and not just the first page.

Comment: Step 1: Enable proper PHP error reporting, so that PHP can tell you what mistakes you’re making. In this case you would get an error message saying that there is no `$isLayout` variable on subsequent pages. You need to read this value back from where you put it - the _session_.

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out. how do i store the $isLayout so that it is being read on subsequent pages?

Comment: You have stored the value into the session, so that is of course also where you read it from again ...

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Works now!

Comment: Actually.. An update... My site has caching enabled. So if two users are browsing the site at the same time the user who visiting that page first ends up determining the layout of the page. Is there any way around this besides disabling caching?

Comment: What kind of caching are you talking about here? Some kind of cache on the server, that writes static files or sth. like this? That of course won’t work if you want the page to be individualized on a per-user basis.

Comment: Caching that writes static files. 

Is there anyway to pass the variable on the front-end? Perhaps via javascript whereby I still load everything but modify the div class to have a "display;hidden; or display:none; css tag so certain elements are just hidden.

Comment: Or perhaps drop a cookie on the users website that will activate certain divs on the page?

Comment: Yeah, server-side sessions and heavy whole-page caching don't work together well. A cookie or an entry in local storage that gets read by JavaScript might be the better alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use $_COOKIE to store the information.
Or you can define the variable in a separate document and require it on the document you need it.